# Regex to replace newlines not working on nodejs as intended

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, vscode-extensions

I have regex which I have tested on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/l1LdQs/1) however when I use the same in nodejs it does not replace the newlines. The regex is `/([ ]*\n)+/gm`. It is supposed to replace multiple newlines with a single newline. The code is as follows. This code is a part of my vscode extension. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
function format(str) {
    const regex = /([ ]*\n)+/gm;
    const subst = `\n`;
    const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
    return result;
}
```

```js
function format(str) {
  const regex = /([ ]*\n)+/gm;
  const subst = `\n`;
  const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
  return result;
}


console.log(format(`abc
      
d

s




  

             

s`));
```

Comment: And if you use  `/( *\r?\n)+/g`? What about ``/(?:\s*\n)+/g``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably that problem is related to CRLF line endings.

You can use

```js
str.replace(/(?:\s*\n)+/g, '\n')
```

Note you do not need `m` flag here.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const str = "abc\r\n      \r\nd\r\n\r\ns\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\n             \r\n\r\ns";
console.log(str.replace(/(?:\s*\n)+/g, '\n'));

const str2 = "abc\n      \nd\n\ns\n\n\r\n\r\n\n  \n\r\n             \n\ns";
console.log(str2.replace(/(?:\s*\n)+/g, '\n'));
```